# How to embed a Google WebApp in an email

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, html-email

I'm building a webapp that will allow a group of sales persons to provide quick updates on sales oportunitites assigned to them.

Right now, they get an email with a link to go to the WebApp (created with Apps Script) and their input is then saved into a spreadsheet. Is there a way to embed the WebApp directly into the email so I can skip the step where they go to a different site? I'm trying to build this as easy as possible for them.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Some guidance questions: Are you aware of the moderm email content limitations? What make you think that it's possible to embed a web app in an email? Should this work on any email client? Is this something that should work for any user or just for few users?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have a web app, or part of a web app, in an email.

But there are other solutions if they use Gmail:

- build a [Gmail addon](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail) (or Outlook plugin)
- create [dynamic emails](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail) (probably works with other mail providers)

Comment: Thank you! I believe the dynamic emails will work great with what I'm looking for. I'll start reading to understand how it works.